# Почему в Webpack подключают, казалось бы, одинаковые плагины?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Вот, к примеру, популярная библиотека Buefy: https://github.com/buefy/buefy/blob/dev/package.json
Мы видим, что на строчках 70 и 79 подключены @babel/core и babel-core. И у других плагинов встречал такое. Так и надо, или забыли убрать?

Comment: Скорее всего, это осталось с миграции пакета `babel` на scoped package (с @-именем). Старое имя пакета вреда не приносит, потому что старый пакет обычно удаляется из npm при публикации нового namespased пакета (то есть, попытка установки deprecated пакета просто будет безуспешной, и он будет пропущен: ошибок прерывающих выполнение установки - не возникнет). Таким образом, ближе вариант "забыли убрать", хотя он не совсем верен.

Comment: @yar85 , понял, спасибо